# Arcpy unzipping script: ERROR 000714 Error in executing: cmd.exe /C

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing-service, error-000714

I wrote script for unzip archive with GDB.
It works locally, i.e from ArcMap.

But when I publish scrypt as geoprocessing service, it doesn't work:

> ERROR 000714: Error in script Zip22. Error in executing: cmd.exe /C

Script:

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys
import traceback
import zipfile
import re

class LicenseError(Exception):
    pass

def unzip(zipFileName):
    try:
        path = os.path.dirname(zipFileName)
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipFileName, 'r')
        gdb_name = None
        for name in zip.namelist():
            if '.gdb' in name.lower():
                gdb_name = name.replace('/', os.sep)
                break
        if not gdb_name:
            raise Exception('zip file has no gdb')
        zip.extractall(path)
        zip.close()
        return path + os.sep + gdb_name
    except RuntimeError:
        zip.close()
        arcpy.AddWarning(get_ID_message(86133))

def get_ID_message(ID):
    return re.sub("%1|%2", "%s", arcpy.GetIDMessage(ID))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        zipFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
        gdb_name = unzip(zipFile)
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, gdb_name)

    except:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
        pymsg = "ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n        " + str(sys.exc_type) + ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
        arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
```

Similar script with archiving GDB to zip works fine both locally and at server.

What's wrong in this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was not in script text, but in script object in ArcMap.

When I checked `Run Python script in process` and publish this script, it began to work at server too.